# SMTP Error (530) 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to use port 587 in roundcubemail running in the same machine as my mail server, and I am always receiving this error:

```
SMTP Error (530): Failed to set sender "X" (5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first).
```

I have already changed,

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
```

to

```
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
```

and nothing happens, and I have already 'submission' uncommented. Those was the solutions that I have found to solve this problem, but till now no result here.

Main.cf:
http://pastebin.com/aEtC0AJt

Master.cf:
http://pastebin.com/023uu2T8

System specs:
 1. PHP Version 5.6.25
 2. Postfix
 3. MacOS 10.12

I don't know if it is related, but I cannot login through IMAP port 993.

I am only able to use ports 25 and 143 without SSL.

I cannot send mails internally, all mails pass through my ISP mail server, where my email domain is.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to imap not listening on a given port: this is a completely different service. May be served by cyrus-imapd, dovecot, courrier, could also involve some imap proxy such as nginx, ... depending on your setup, there's probably something else to fix. Let us know.

Now regarding the `must issue a STARTTLS` error, according to your `main.cf`, we have:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
```

You'll probably want to add `permit_mynetworks` to your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. And also make sure your roundcube is configured to connect on `127.0.0.1` or arguably add your IP address to `mynetworks`. What did you set as `$config['smtp_server']` in roundcube `config.php`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply SYN!Yes i know i was just letting know, because i am just not able to use (send/receive mails) both TTL/SSL ports. I forgot to mentioned that i am using dovecot to IMAP/POP. So with that error from SMTP port 587, i was not able to solve that error with adding permit_networks to smtpd_recipient_restrictions. In every smtp and imap config at roundcube i was using localhost, and it works but just for port 25.

Comment: I have read somewhere that PHP version 5.6 could be doing this. I saw a workaround where someone have downgraded PHP to version 5.5 and have solve avoid this problem. But cannot find anything related, dont know if could be from PHP. I have checked php and it is being use, through LibreSSL.